# Invite Friends to try the App

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to implement invite Friends From Facebook/Contacts/etc to try my Android App. Facebook SDK has WebDialog based Requests to invite friends to try their app. However I want to create more personalize look such shown in the image below.How can I have list of friends like this and also send them a notification of invitation to try out my Android App .

Please check the link of image to see what I'm looking for.

[image]

Comment: How exactly the invitations are sent from the example you've shown- can you pls check

Comment: Did you tried sending these invitations? Do they send the app request or they publish on wall or send notification?

Comment: Sahil as mentioned in the question. I want to do this. I can get the list of friends but how do i do the inviting part. that itself is the question here. Facebook SDK has Webdialogs which bring a web dialog which I do not wish to implement.

Comment: You are still not answering what I'm asking from you. Anyways you can wait for some response from other guys

Comment: Sahil its a prototype for the design. I haven't implemented the request part. thats what i'm asking in this question.
how would i be able to send invitations if i dont know how to implement it. so no question of app request or publish on wall or send notifications. Coz i haven't implemented it. And thats my question, how to do it.